# Negative voltage source (-0.55V)

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, negative

I am using one of the IC in my project and it needs -0.55V with maximum of 220mA. I will appreciate your recommendation for this solution,since i search a lot but unable to find any valid solution for this negative voltage.

How do I get a negative voltage of 0.55V that can source at least 220mA?

Comment: What IC? Datasheet?

Comment: its a modulator driver called MAOM-003414 from MACOM but the data sheet is confidential.

Comment: Is it important that that driver's GND is at the same voltage at your circuit's ground?

Comment: yes it is important.

Comment: Any infos about the voltages you already have? The precision you're looking for?

Comment: i have 6V,2.5V,2.35V for the same IC on same board but the only thing is -ve 0.55V is remaining.

Comment: And also i have 5V and 12V on the same board for some  other external components

Comment: Ask MACOM for an advise.

Answer (score 2):

> i have 5V

You could do it like this. Take this circuit that produces -5 volts from +5 volts: -

[image]

Then use a unity gain non-inverting op-amp powered from +/- 5V connected to a PNP emitter follower with the feedback loop from the emitter. Set the input voltage to the op-amp at -0.55 volts with a potential divider. Or use a push-pull amplifier like this: -

[image]

You should be able to get away without the NPN transistor for your application.

Comment: I did find a -0.5V ,-5V adjustable LDO from Analog (ADP7183). It could maybe help get rid of the Op Amp and transistors. However, its package isn't the easiest to manually solder.

Comment: @HatimB yes that looks a good find to replace op-amp and transistors. You have to watch power dissipation of these small devices though so maybe pad the input voltage down to -2 volts with a series resistor.

Answer (score 0):

There are 78XX DC to DC converters that are pin compatible with the regulators, they are easy to solder and can also sink and source current. Depending on the way they are wired they can even generate negative voltages. After you generate a -3.3 or -5V you could put an LDO of your choosing after that. Not all 78XX converters can source and sink current so make sure it is suited for negative application.   [image: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cui-inc/P7805-Q24-S12-S/102-2708-ND/4009629]

Comment: Thanks for the above idea and even i got one DC to DC with an output of -3.3V,which then i followed by a voltage divider to get -0.55V. So am i right in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a buck cobverter in buck-boost configuration: output connected to gbd and all gnd points connected to negative voltage. The problem is that in most cases vfb os higher than 0.55V, so you would need to amplify feedback instead using resistor divider. But i would try it. And i am also pretty sure there are dc/dc converters with vfb<0.5v